# Combine React Native with Unity

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unity-game-engine

I want to combine React Native and Unity. Is there a possibility to write React code and run it in Unity. I have experience in React and React Native and I want to start Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. For the current version of React Native (0.59), you can't write code to Unity. Because Unity follows C# architecture for game development which is a totally different environment and technology.

But it is possible to create communication and compatibility between two deferent environments using bridge concepts, **like building Android and iOS apps in react-native.** So in future, it may start support for Unity but currently, you can't do stuff like this.